# UIActivityViewController completion handler returns true even if the sharing returns error

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I use UIActivityViewController to share a post to WhatsApp the whatsApp application shows an error that account is not configured, but the UIActivityViewController returns a status as completed. I want to know how to alert the user that the issue happened. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Show us your code. Have you checked the value of `activityError` in your completion handler? Do you have the same issue with other extensions, or just with WhatsApp?

Comment: I am getting activityError as nil. For Facebook I am getting the completion status as False.

Comment: Might be a bug in the WhatsApp share extension. If you correctly detect errors for other share extensions, but not that one, it's more probably on their side. File a bug report with them.

Comment: I have the same problem.  E.g., If I put iPhone in airplane mode and go to share via WhatsApp, it takes me to the WhatsApp interface.  When I tap 'Send', an error message sates 'Could not connect to WhatsApp service.  Please try again later.'  I tap 'OK' and cancel (still within WhatsApp) and it returns to my app --> more specifically works through completionWithItemsHandler and triggers 'completed'.  I have had similar problems with other types (e.g. Tumblr, Gmail - if not previously logged in to those apps).  Apple have told me it is not their problem but ask me to file bug reports.